# Error about Amazon Product API with bottlenose

Tags: python, amazon-product-api, bottlenose

I am using the bottlenose for Amazon Product API. I simply created some codes and met the error below:

Code I created:

```
ak = "my access key"   
sk = "My secret key"

import bottlenose
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(ak, sk)
response=amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId="0596520999", ResponseGroup="Images", SearchIndex="Books", IdType="ISBN",Style="http://xml2json-xslt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xml2json.xslt") % reference from the README file of bottlenose
```

Here is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/amazontest", line 6, in <module>
    response=amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId="0596520999", ResponseGroup="Images", SearchIndex="Books", IdType="ISBN",Style="http://xml2json-xslt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xml2json.xslt")
  File "C:\Users\supercoco\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\bottlenose\api.py", line 104, in __call__
    response = urllib2.urlopen(api_request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Is there anyone know what is the problem? I appreicate your answer!

Thanks

-CC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in

```
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(ak, sk)
```

you need to add a third parameter: service Tag.

```
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(ak, sk, service_tag)
```